# Обработка "необработанных исключений"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, исключения

В ходе работы моего приложения *.Net Windows Forms*, при возникновении необработанных исключений появляется окно с текстом сообщения исключения, содержимым свойства `StackTrace` и кнопками <kbd>Продолжить</kbd> и <kbd>Выход</kbd> [image: Окно, появляющееся при возникновении необработанного исключения]

1) Можно ли настроить проект, чтобы при возникновении необработанных исключений, происходило что-то другое?

2) Можно ли поставить обработчик события на появление этого окна, дабы записывать в логи необработанные исключения?

Если пользователь нажмёт <kbd>Выход</kbd>, приложение прерывается сразу и не срабатывает даже событие закрытия главного окна приложения.

3) Можно ли поставить обработчик события на нажатие кнопки <kbd>Выход</kbd> ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужны события [`AppDomain.UnhandledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx) и [`Application.ThreadException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception(v=vs.110).aspx). Также может оказаться полезным блок try...catch в методе Main.

Эти три способа дают возможность перехватить исключения прежде, чем они дойдут до стандартных обработчиков (т.е. приведенное вами окно показано не будет). Если надо сообщить об ошибке пользователю - вам придется делать это самостоятельно.

Нажатие кнопки "Выход" перехватить без мега-костылей нельзя.

Comment: добавлю, что так и не удалось никак перехватить исключения происходящие вне ГУИ-потока. Их пришлось завернуть все в `try-catch`

Answer (score -1):

Чуть ответ [@PavelMayorov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547281/6) дополню примером!

```
try
{
    //  цикл, функция, обрабочик .....

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // ex -  сообщение об ошибке(пиши его в лог или как в примере сообшение выводи)

    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "xxx", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); 

    return; 
}
```

Comment: Речь про необработанные исключения

Comment: Т.е. вы пишите как поймать исключение в коде, а спрашиваю что делать, если пропустил. Вы никак не дополняете ответ от Pavel Mayorov