# UnhandledExceptionHandler на C# вне Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения, логирование

Есть проект. Начальство, спустя более 40к строк кода решило добавить логирование. Обычное, уровня Debug, уже добавил, теперь пришёл черед Exception-ов.

Есть вариант прошить всё `try {} catch {log.write(message)}`, но, по-моему, это не самый оптимальный вариант.

Попытался использовать `UnhandledExceptionHandler`, однако вне студии (да и банально в запуске без отладки) handler работать не хочет.

**Вопрос**: не сталкивался ли кто с подобным и что можете посоветовать в таком случае?
Т.е. задача: перехватывать все (не только фатальные) исключения в релизе.

Приложение WinForms .NET 2.0 (да, всё настолько плохо:)

Добавлено:

Вешаю `Handler` в `Main` перед `Application.Run(mainForm)`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

Код обработки

```
static void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object source, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            logger.Error("Message: " + ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message);
            var st = new StackTrace(((Exception)e.ExceptionObject), true);
            for (int i = 0; i < st.FrameCount; i++)
            {
                var frame = st.GetFrame(i);
                var method = frame.GetMethod();
                //if (method.DeclaringType.FullName.Contains("AMT"))
                {
                    logger.Error("Source: " + method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + method.Name);
                    logger.Error("Line: " + frame.GetFileLineNumber());
                }
            }
        }
```

Код просто не отрабатывает, как будто его и нет. В самой студии в режиме отладки всё нормально - и брекпоинт можно поставить, и лог пишется. Как только запускаю .exe напрямую - метода как-будто нет.

**Обновление**

Решение проблемы:

В Main:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(ThreadExceptionHandler);
```

И три метода, два из которых перехватывают исключения и один вспомогательный для вывода инфы для юзера.

```
static void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object source, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            logger.Error("Message: " + ((Exception)e.ExceptionObject).Message);
            var st = new StackTrace(((Exception)e.ExceptionObject), true);
            for (int i = 0; i < st.FrameCount; i++)
            {
                var frame = st.GetFrame(i);
                var method = frame.GetMethod();
                if (method.DeclaringType.FullName.Contains("AMT"))
                {
                    logger.Error("Source: " + method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + method.Name);
                    logger.Error("Line: " + frame.GetFileLineNumber());
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ThreadExceptionHandler(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            logger.Error("Message: " + e.Exception.Message);
            var st = new StackTrace(e.Exception, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < st.FrameCount; i++)
            {
                var frame = st.GetFrame(i);
                var method = frame.GetMethod();
                if (method.DeclaringType.FullName.Contains("AMT"))
                {
                    logger.Error("Source: " + method.DeclaringType.FullName + "." + method.Name);
                    logger.Error("Line: " + frame.GetFileLineNumber());
                }
            }

            DialogResult result = DialogResult.Cancel;
            try
            {
                result = ShowThreadExceptionDialog("Windows Forms Error", e.Exception);
            }
            catch
            {
                try
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Fatal Windows Forms Error", "Fatal Windows Forms Error", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
                }
                finally
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
            if (result == DialogResult.Abort)
                Application.Exit();
        }

        private static DialogResult ShowThreadExceptionDialog(string title, Exception e)
        {
            string errorMsg = "An application error occurred. Please contact the adminstrator " +
                "with the following information:\n\n";
            errorMsg = errorMsg + e.Message + "\n\nStack Trace:\n" + e.StackTrace;
            return MessageBox.Show(errorMsg, title, MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
        }
```

Comment: Вы умудрились написать столько текста, причем не рассказать ни что за тип проекта (asp.net? wpf? wtf?), ни что вы пытались сделать (код?), ни что конкретно не работает (`handler работать не хочет` - что это значит?). Вам бы шпионом быть, столько текста и по сути ничего не сказано :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Обработка "необработанных исключений"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547258/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 0):

Подпишитесь на `Application.ThreadException`

Исключения из ГУИ-потока так ловятся. А вот исключения из прочих потоков, просто крашат приложение, поэтому их пришлось завернуть в `try-catch` все.

Answer (score 0):

У меня приведенный код не работает ни под отладчиком, ни без него. Дело в том, что режим `UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException` перенаправляет исключение стандартному обработчику потока (который для основного потока WinForms выводит знаменитое сообщение с красным крестом), и до вашего обработчика ничего не доходит. Замена на `UnhandledExceptionMode.ThrowException` решает проблему.